Caret is hiding behind UITextField border
I'm adding offset to caret to it was not just behind symbol, but 2 points away.
public final class MyTextField: UITextField {

     override public func caretRect(for position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect {
          super.caretRect(for: position).offsetBy(dx: 2, dy: 0)
     }
}

But when entered text is as long as TextField, cursor (caret) become not visible. How to keep entered text + caret inside TextField bounds?

Just use inset(by:) instead of offset By(dx:dy:)
